# How to append data in array in formdata?

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I'm Trying to send tag's ID in a array as tags will be multiple for a single blog.

```
const tagsList = data.tags.map((item: {
  value: number;
  label: string;
}) => {
  return {
    label: item.label, value: item.value
  }
```

here is the structure of data.tags
[image]

```
}

)
details.append('tags', tagsList)
```

I'm Trying in this way but i'm unable to do so
[image]

Can anyone help me sending the ids of tags in an array? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add the structure of data.tags

Comment: @Nizar I have added. Thankyou

Comment: Can you also please share what you expect tagsList to be (if the code was correct, what would tagsList look like)? I don't fully understand. Where is the id of the tag stored? In item.label or item.value?

Comment: I want to send data in tags as[8,9] which is the id of tags(multiple). And Each tags has label and value. I want to send its value

Comment: But where does the id come from? data.tags only includes label and value, but no id.

Comment: Value itself is a id

Comment: So just to correct your previous comment, the array should be [8,10] and not [8,9] if we were to use data.tags you added in the picture in the question?

Comment: yes. Basically trying to send those value

Comment: Check out the answer

Answer (score 1):

Here's a the code:

1. There's an array of objects that include tags - a `label` and `value` for each tag. (Yours is called `data.tags`).
2. We declare a `const tagsList`, and use the `map` method on tags to return only the `value` in each tag.

Your use of `map` was inaccurate, you don't really have to pass the structure of each tag into the `map` method. Feel free to check out how map works [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Let me know if the code works for you :)

```js
  const tags = [{value:8,label:'2'},{value:10,label:'2'}]

  const tagsList = tags.map((item) => {
    return item.value
  })

  console.log(tagsList)
```

Comment: I am getting tags: 8,10 in network header but throws this error "["Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str."]" and throws 400 error.

Comment: Thats a django question I assume. Now you're going to have to ask another question on the django forum :) The goal of this question is to give you the array you need in the form you wanted

Comment: Thankyou for the help and sharing your thoughts. It solved the goal of this question.